# Help with ruby script, (if line contains, ignore)

Tags: ruby

First, Let me apologize as I know NOTHING about ruby. I can read through the code and understand whats going on, but have never written any code.

I have a script we use to parse some log files that we obtained from someone a long time ago.

```
# format the csv data into an sql insert query
def FormatToSQL(file_name)
  $logger.info(caller) { "creating SQL insert q's" }
  formatted_data = []
  data_lines = []
  open("#{LOCAL_DIR}/#{file_name}") { |f| data_lines = f.readlines }
  data_lines.each do |r|
    data = []
    rdata = r.split(' ')
    rdata.each { |e| data.push("'#{e}'") }
    data.unshift('DEFAULT')
    sql_data = data.join(',')
    formatted_data.push(sql_data)
  end
  return(formatted_data)
end
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# M  A   I    N

$logger = Logger.new("//var/www/metaquery/calllogger.log", 3, 1024000)
$logger.info(caller) { "start" }
now = Time.now().gmtime() - 3600  ## files are name using UTC
file_name = sprintf("calllog_%s_%02d_%02d_%02d.log", now.year, now.month.to_i,     now.day.to_i, now.hour.to_i)
if(doSFTPPull(file_name)) then
  ConnectDB()
  formatted_sql = FormatToSQL(file_name)
  formatted_sql.each { |sql| $local_conn.query("insert into #{DB_TABLE} values(#{sql})") }
else
  # we did not download the new file, report to ???
  false
end
$logger.info(caller) { "normal end" }
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The log contains thousands of rows of records, like so

```
2xx3xx2xx7 2xx3xx56xx 07/28/11.19:55:45 19:55:46 20:00:00 2 4092 - - N - - TER - A T -
```

However, we enabled some new QoS Stats, and it adds lines like this,

```
VQM: 2xx3xx00xx 08/12/11.13:02:07 - - - - 20ms 0 0
```

I want to add a statement to ignore anylines beginning with VQM, as this throws the column count off on the MySQL Inserts, ultimately causing the query to fail, thus causing the script to fail.

How would I acheive this? Again, sorry for being a complete Noob with Ruby. Im only a php guy, and not even good at that. lol

I do know, the area probably has to be in
    data_lines.each do |r|

where the code would be, and likely a if/then with some regex. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
data_lines.each do |r|
  next if r.match(/^VQM/) #will skip this one if the line starts VQM
  #everything else as before
end
```

Comment: Or more succinctly: `next if r =~ /^VQM/`

Comment: @Phrogz Yeah, that too :) I can never remember which way round the equals and the tilde go in that operator :/

Comment: @Skilldrick: A way to remember is to think that `=~` starts with `=` because it compares two strings without modyfing them, while operators like `+=` or `*=` have on the left side the operation that will modify the argument on left

Answer (score 1):

```
data_lines.each do |r|
    next if r[0,4] == 'VQM:'
    data = []
    rdata = r.split(' ')
    rdata.each { |e| data.push("'#{e}'") }
    data.unshift('DEFAULT')
    sql_data = data.join(',')
    formatted_data.push(sql_data)
  end
```

Or alternatively

```
data_lines.reject{|line| line[0,4] == 'VQM:'}.each do |r| 
  data = []
  rdata = r.split(' ')
  rdata.each { |e| data.push("'#{e}'") }
  data.unshift('DEFAULT')
  sql_data = data.join(',')
  formatted_data.push(sql_data)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
data_lines.each do |r|
```

add:

```
next if r.match(/^VQM/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fastest choice is what others have suggested (skip the line during the single iteration):

```
data_lines.each do |r|
  next if r =~ /^VQM/
end
```

Alternatively, you can pare down your set of data_lines to only have the correct lines first. (Note additional suggested changes below.)

```
def FormatToSQL(file_name)
  $logger.info(caller) { "creating SQL insert q's" }
  formatted_data = []

  # Use IO.readlines to more simply slurp your values
  data_lines = IO.readlines( File.join(LOCAL_DIR,file_name) )

  # Modify the array, throwing out lines where this does not return false/nil
  data_lines.reject!{ |r| r =~ /^VQM/ }

  # modify the array, throwing out trailing newlines per line;
  # invokes the .chomp method on each item in the array and uses the
  # result of that as the new value for the array
  data_lines.map!(&:chomp)

  data_lines.each do |r|
    data = r.split(' ').map{ |e| "'#{e}'" }
    data.unshift('DEFAULT')
    formatted_data << data.join(',')
  end

  # It is idiomatic (and slightly faster) to not use the 'return' keyword
  # since the last value of your method _is_ what is returned.
  formatted_data
end
```

Finally, here's how I would personally write your method, using a more functional style:

```
def FormatToSQL(file_name)
  $logger.info(caller) { "creating SQL insert q's" }

  IO.readlines( File.join(LOCAL_DIR,file_name) ).map do |line|
    unless line =~ /^VQM/
      [
        'DEFAULT',
        *line.chomp.split(' ').map{ |e| "'#{e}'" }
      ].join(',')
    end
  end.compact
end
```

We map each line of the file to the new value unless the line begins with `VQM`; in that case, the result of the block is `nil`, and the final call to `.compact` removes all `nil` values from the array which is our return value.

Answer (score 0):

in `data_lines.each do |r|` the first line should be

```
next if /^VQM/
```

This will cause the next iteration to begin immediately (this is the same as a continue statement in c)

Comment: Damn! You beat me! (but you're not checking the line...)

Comment: I believe the "r" is implicit here (like perl's $_)

Comment: Well, I stand corrected! I never used Perl so I write Ruby more like Python than Perl :)

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work - `warning: regex literal in condition`

Comment: `%w[foo bar].each{ |s| puts "YAY" if /oo/ }` (no output); the literal in the condition is matched against `$_`, not any local block params.